Swapping left and right hand sides of an equation
My goal is to get the rule t->(v[t]-v[0])/a from equation v[t]==a t+v[0]. During the process, I come to change the left and right sides, so I wonder if there is a function or neat way that can do this. (There are *Sides functions in the documentation and I think there might be a function or similar one that swaps sides.)
expr=v[t]\[Equal]a t+v[0];
ApplySides[(#-v[0])/a &,%]    (*how to swap left and right side of the result?*)
Rule@@%    (*Goal is t-> (v[t]-v[0])/a*)


if you want to swap sides, why not just do expr[[2]] == expr[[1]] ?  Why do you need a rule for?    and to move everything to one side expr[[1]] - expr[[2]] == 0  https://i.sstatic.net/AJnmhN78.png

Looks like an XY Problem.

Thank you for your answer; I've learned that the Part function seems to be the best tool for this case;
swapSides[expr_]:=expr[[2]]==expr[[1]];
expr=v[t][Equal]a t+v[0];
ApplySides[(#-v[0])/a &,%]
swapSides[%];
Rule@@%

To make your code more robust you should write swapSides[expr_Equal] so it only works on equation.

@Nasser Thank you for your answer; I finally modified like this; swapSides[expr_Equal]:=expr[[2]]==expr[[1]];
expr=v[t]==a t+v[0];
Rule@@swapSides@ApplySides[(#-v[0])/a &,%]

Also Solve[expr /. a*t -> a*h, h][[1, 1]] /. h -> t

If you know the final form, why you cannot simply type it? I am voting to close this post as senseless.

Why not using Reverse?
expr = v[t] == a t + v[0];
ApplySides[(# - v[0])/a &, %]
Reverse@%



Or with ToRules.
expr = v[t] == a t + v[0];
ApplySides[(# - v[0])/a &, %]
ToRules@Reverse@%




Thank you for your answer, and letting me know the ToRules and so its relted document named Manipulating Equations and Inequalities. And also the usage of  Reverse & ToRules combination. Thank you again
